# PHP get words from a word using pspell_check

Tags: php, dictionary, spell-checking

I had a PHP string which contains **English** words. I want to extract all the possible words from the string, not by `explode()` by space as I have only a word. I mean extraction of words from a word.

**Example:** With the word `"stackoverflow"`, I need to extract `stack, over, flow, overflow` all of them.

I am using `pspell_check()` for spell checking. I am currently getting the following combination.

```
--> sta
--> stac
--> stack
and so on.
```

So I found the only the words matching `stack` but I want to find the following words. Notice that I don't want the final word as I've already.

```
--> stack
--> over
--> flow
```

---

**My Code:**

```
$myword = "stackoverflow";
$word_length = strlen($myword);
$myword_prediction = $myword[0].$myword[1]; 
//(initial condition as words detection starts after 3rd index)

for ($i=2; $i<$word_length; $i++) {
    $myword_prediction .= $myword[$i];
    if (pspell_check(pspell_new("en"), $myword_prediction)) 
    {
        $array[] = $myword_prediction;
    }
}

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: do the words have to be sequential, like in your examples, or can you use a word like fowl, or owl, or stock?

Comment: yeah, the words are in sequentional order, such that the stack over flow are 3 words which are required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about if you have an outer loop like this. The first time through you start at the first character of $myword. The second time through you start at the second character, and so on.

```
$myword = "stackoverflow";
$word_length = strlen($myword);

$startLetter = 0;

while($startLetter < $word_length-2 ){
    $myword_prediction = $myword[$startLetter] . $myword[$startLetter +1];
    for ($i=$startLetter; $i<$word_length; $i++) {
        $myword_prediction .= $myword[$i];
        if (pspell_check(pspell_new("en"), $myword_prediction)) {
            $array[] = $myword_prediction;
        }
    }
$startLetter ++;
}
```

Comment: Well, I need a condition that not to check the first two indecies after every founded word.

Comment: so, if you find a word that starts on $myword[3] , the next search starts on $myword[5] ?

Comment: Yeah, because the pspell_check() detects the words correction after 3 indiceis. so in my opinion, it would be after 3 indicies not the 2 as whole. I did that in my code the concatination of first two indicies and the the third one in the loop

Comment: In general, I need the word detection after 3 indicies, such that on every successfull word spellings, it should start the next indicies from the fourth index. i.e after 3.

Comment: ok, check my edits. I might have the edge cases wrong, but you could fiddle with it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you would need to get all substrings, and check each one:

```
function get_all_substrings($input){
    $subs = array();
    $length = strlen($input);
    for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++){
        for($j=$i; $j<$length; $j++){
            $subs[] = substr($input, $i, $j);               
        }
    }
    return array_unique($subs);
}

$substrings = get_all_substrings("stackoverflow");
$pspell_link = pspell_new("en");
$words = array_filter($substrings, function($word) use ($pspell_link) {
             return pspell_check($pspell_link, $word);
         });
var_dump($words);
```

Comment: Well, I need a condition that not to check the first two indecies after every founded word.